# Fit all height for all screen

Tags: html, css, responsive

I would like to ask how you fit the height of each section for every screen. I tried doing the **Height: 100%** but it didn't work. It's for a parallax site too, I tried it for the homepage (layout below) but I really don't know how to make it work. Thank you in advance for the help! :)

[image: PHOTO HERE.]

Comment: We can't help you much by a photo. Please, post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried,

```
.backgroundDiv {
 height:100vh;
 width:100vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want 100% **height** of your div you need to give 100% height to your **html** and **body** also. Try this example. I hope it will help you.

**HTML**

```
<div class="demo"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.demo {
  background: #000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```